# Angular Type Script Router Configuration not working. Always redirects to home Page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am pretty new to Angular. When i hit the app with localhost:9500/pp URL, it always direct to the home page.

**This is my `app.module.ts`**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NavComponent} from './nav/nav.component';

import {GrowlModule, MenubarModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

import {FlightModule} from './flight/flight.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]),
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule,
        FlightModule,
        MenubarModule,
        GrowlModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**This is my `flight.module.ts`**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewFlightComponent} from './view-flight.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {DataTableModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule ({
    declarations: [
        ViewFlightComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        DataTableModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {path: 'pp', component: ViewFlightComponent}
        ])
    ],
    providers: []
})

export class FlightModule {
}
```

**This is my `ViewFlightComponent`**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    templateUrl: './view-flight.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./view-flight.component.css']
})

export class ViewFlightComponent {
}
```

This is `my view-flight.comoponent.html`

```
<div>
    Hello ..
</div>
```

When i hit the app with `localhost:9500/pp` URL, it always direct to the home page.

I tried a lot.. Not sure what I am missing. Please help

Comment: Isn't there any error in the console?

Comment: No. I opened the chrome console and found no error

Comment: Probably you have missed to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app component template

Comment: Please check the answer, that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have missed to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app-component` template.

And also you should consider adding route to your child module in your app-module.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
   { path : '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path : '', loadChildren: 'app/flight/flight.module#FlightModule' }
 ])
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebejib)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: But it is loading within the same page. Not as a separate page. There is picture in my app.component. when i hit the url /pp, it loads the content of the flights, along with the content of the app.component.html. Any idea on how to tackle this ?

Comment: That's the root component, inside which all the custom components reside. We usually place `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` within `app.component.html`. That is why you get the custom component displayed under `app-component`.